# How to correctly join multiple tables on non-primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to create a view where the user sees one line per "Batch" joined so that when the "Batch" from the different tables match - then they should go together as one line. But if either table on itself has the "Batch" it should also be added to the result as a row with "NULL" in the other columns.

I think the problem is with how I join the tables. But I can't quite figure out the problem.

```
CREATE TABLE #ItemTable ([Item] nvarchar(16))
CREATE TABLE #LocationTable ([Item] nvarchar(16), [Batch] nvarchar(32), [Location] nvarchar(13), [Quantity] int)
CREATE TABLE #OrderTable ([Item] nvarchar(16), [Batch] nvarchar(32), [Quantity] int)
CREATE TABLE #BookingTable ([Item] nvarchar(16), [Batch] nvarchar(32), [Quantity] int)

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- CURRENT RESULT:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Item    Batch   Location        QuantityOnLocation  OrderedQuantity BookedQuantity
--  1000    1       Location_1      10                  NULL            NULL
--  1000    22      Location_2      10                  NULL            NULL
--  2000    333     Location_3      0                   10              NULL
--  2000    4444    Location_4      10                  NULL            NULL
--  3000    666666  NULL            NULL                10              10

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- DESIRED RESULT:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
--  Item    Batch   Location        QuantityOnLocation  OrderedQuantity BookedQuantity
--  1000    1       Location_1      10                  NULL            10
--  1000    22      Location_2      10                  NULL            0
--  1000    55555   NULL            NULL                NULL            10
--  2000    333     Location_3      0                   10              NULL
--  2000    4444    Location_4      10                  NULL            NULL
--  3000    666666  NULL            NULL                10              10


INSERT INTO #ItemTable ([Item]) VALUES 
('1000'), 
('2000'), 
('3000')

INSERT INTO #LocationTable ([Item], [Batch], [Location], [Quantity]) VALUES 
('1000', '1', 'Location_1', 10), 
('1000', '22', 'Location_2', 10), 
('2000', '333', 'Location_3', 0),
('2000', '4444', 'Location_4', 10)

INSERT INTO #OrderTable ([Item], [Batch], [Quantity]) VALUES 
('2000', '333', 10), 
('3000', '666666', 10)

INSERT INTO #BookingTable ([Item], [Batch], [Quantity]) VALUES 
('1000', '1', 10), 
('1000', '55555', 10), 
('3000', '666666', 10)


SELECT 
    [Item].[Item] AS [Item], 
    COALESCE([Location].[Batch], [Order].[Batch], [Booking].[Batch]) AS [Batch],
    [Location].[Location] AS [Location], 
    [Location].[Quantity] AS [QuantityOnLocation],
    [Order].[Quantity] AS [OrderedQuantity],
    [Booking].Quantity AS [BookedQuantity]
FROM 
    #ItemTable AS [Item]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT [Item], [Quantity], [Batch], [Location]
        FROM #LocationTable)
    AS [Location] ON [Location].[Item] = [Item].[Item] 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT [Item], [Quantity], [Batch]
        FROM #OrderTable) 
    AS [Order] ON [Order].[Item] = [Item].[Item] 
        AND ISNULL([Order].[Batch], '') = ISNULL([Location].[Batch], [Order].[Batch]) 

    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        SELECT [Item], [Quantity], [Batch]
        FROM #BookingTable) 
    AS [Booking] ON [Order].[Item] = [Item].[Item]
        AND ISNULL([Booking].[Batch], '') = COALESCE([Location].[Batch], [Order].[Batch], [Booking].[Batch]) 
WHERE
    ISNULL([Location].[Quantity], 0) <> 0
    OR ISNULL([Order].[Quantity], 0) <> 0
    OR ISNULL([Booking].Quantity, 0) <> 0


DROP TABLE #ItemTable
DROP TABLE #LocationTable
DROP TABLE #BookingTable 
DROP TABLE #OrderTable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a typo (I think) on your last join, this bit:

```
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT [Item], [Quantity], [Batch]
    FROM #BookingTable) 
AS [Booking] ON [Order].[Item] = [Item].[Item]
```

Should that not be:

```
ON [Booking].[Item] = [Item].[Item]
```

I rewrote your query slightly to this:

```
SELECT 
    i.Item AS Item, 
    COALESCE(l.Batch, o.Batch, b.Batch) AS Batch,
    l.Location AS Location, 
    l.Quantity AS QuantityOnLocation,
    o.Quantity AS OrderedQuantity,
    b.Quantity AS BookedQuantity
FROM 
    #ItemTable i
    LEFT JOIN #LocationTable l ON l.Item = i.Item
    LEFT JOIN #OrderTable o ON o.Item = i.Item AND o.Batch = ISNULL(l.Batch, o.Batch) 
    LEFT JOIN #BookingTable b ON b.Item = i.Item AND b.Batch = COALESCE(l.Batch, o.Batch, b.Batch) 
WHERE
    ISNULL(l.Quantity, 0) != 0
    OR ISNULL(o.Quantity, 0) != 0
    OR ISNULL(b.Quantity, 0) != 0;
```

Which seems more readable to me, but I guess this is personal preference?

Then I realised that this still doesn't give you what you want, so I refactored it again to get this (which does give you the desired results):

```
WITH UniqueItemBatch AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT Item, Batch FROM #LocationTable
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT Item, Batch FROM #OrderTable
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT Item, Batch FROM #BookingTable)
SELECT 
    u.Item AS Item, 
    u.Batch,
    l.Location AS Location, 
    l.Quantity AS QuantityOnLocation,
    o.Quantity AS OrderedQuantity,
    b.Quantity AS BookedQuantity
FROM
    UniqueItemBatch u
    LEFT JOIN #ItemTable i ON i.Item = u.Item
    LEFT JOIN #LocationTable l ON l.Item = u.Item AND l.Batch = u.Batch
    LEFT JOIN #OrderTable o ON o.Item = u.Item AND o.Batch = u.Batch
    LEFT JOIN #BookingTable b ON b.Item = u.Item AND b.Batch = u.Batch
WHERE
    ISNULL(l.Quantity, 0) != 0
    OR ISNULL(o.Quantity, 0) != 0
    OR ISNULL(b.Quantity, 0) != 0;
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution so far. How would it scale with another table like Booking to be added? Just add the LEFT JOIN and SELECT DISTINCT? (And where, select of course)

Comment: I tried it and it seems to give the result I want even with more tables, and it's very easy to add more. Just gonna do some more testing tomorrow to see if I can find any case where it doesn't work before I mark as an answer.

Comment: Yes, this should be scalable to more tables because it breaks down the work into two parts, one part to determine the unique item/ batch ids, and a second part to bring in any matching data.  If you used your original solution you would end up with some very long COLLATE statements by adding more tables to the mix, and more chance of making a mistake.  The only downside with my approach is the performance might not be quite as good as a "single hit" query?  However, the optimiser might not run this the way it looks on paper... so testing would be best.

Comment: *COALESCE* not COLLATE

Comment: One other thing to note, you could entirely remove the LEFT JOIN to the #ItemTable, as this is now redundant; none of the columns from this table are included in the query, and it's a LEFT JOIN so it doesn't act as a constraint.  I imagine this would be optimised away in any case?

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly for me. I will keep the ItemTable in the real (non-cleaned up) application. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure as to the logic for your final column, but this gives the desired results for the other columns.

To get your query based on either bookings or locations showing as a batch, I have unioned the two tables together in the query.

I would suggest, if possible, revisiting the design of your data structure

```
select 
    item.Item,
    batch.Batch, 
    max(batch.location) as location,
    sum(batch.LQuantity) as QuantityOnLocation,
    orders.Quantity as OrderedQuantity,
    sum(batch.BQuantity) as BookedQuantity
from
    #ItemTable item
        left join 
        (
            select Item, Batch, quantity as BQuantity, null as Location, null  as LQuantity from #BookingTable
            union
            select item, Batch, null, Location, Quantity as LQuantity from #LocationTable
        ) batch
            on item.Item = batch.Item
    left join #OrderTable orders
        on item.Item = orders.Item and batch.Batch = orders.Batch
group by 
    item.Item,
    batch.Batch,    
    orders.Quantity
```

Comment: Sadly I can't change the design of the structure, too many programs are dependent on it..

Comment: How would this solution "scale"? By that I mean if there was another table like Booking?

Comment: It's hard to tell without knowing all the other variables involved.

Comment: Basically a copy of Booking and add another column to the result.

Answer (score -1):

I think I would prefer a different approach. How about you take all the batchnumbers and add all the columns as empty columns. Then you update the different columns form each table.

Like this:

```
SELECT INTO #MyTableResult Batch FROM TableA
UNION 
SELECT Batch FROM TableB
```

And so on. The union removed duplicates.

Then you update like:

```
Update #MyTableResult SET Column A = ValueA FROM TableA WHERE 
#MyTableResult.Batch = TableA.Batch.
```

After all updates from your tables are done, then you get the desired result.

Comment: Why use a temp table when you could just join instead? I see a lot of BI developers that don't understand joins that well doing this and absolutely killing productions servers with a terrible inefficient workload.

Comment: @Charleh: The reason is that the logic is easy to read and adjust. Depends also on the size of the tables I guess. In my opinion not a bad option in a lots of use cases. Run some performance tests and you will get a clear picture if this is a nice solution for this particular situation.